# Unable to update Woocommerce Product Permalink

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I am using woocommerce with Auto Rent theme found [here](https://themeforest.net/item/auto-rent-car-rental-wordpress-theme/11214151).

I updated my product permalink using woocommerce permalinks from

```
xyz.com/product/product-name
```

to

```
xyz.com/cars/%product_cat%/product-name.
```

But this change is not being reflected in the website. It is still following the older link structure.
I tried this with localhost as well as cpanel. Still no changes on permalink structure.

Link to my website: carrental.webception.in

**Update:** Check the screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Where you've changed the permalink structure ?

Comment: @the_dramatist sorry for not mentioning that. Check the updated question.

Comment: What is your **Product Category Base** value ?

Comment: @the_dramatist its `cat-type`

Comment: Do you have any **SEO** plugin or **WPML** installed ?

Comment: theme is wpml compatible. But i haven't installed wpml. i tried disabling all plugins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47294/discussion-between-vishwas-navada-k-and-the-dramatist).

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `functions.php`-

```
add_action( 'init', 'the_drmatist_category_base' );
function the_drmatist_category_base() {
// Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
    // The regex to match the incoming URL
        'news/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/][^f][^e][^e][^d]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$', //here my changes to exclude 'feed'
        // The resulting internal URL
        'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]',
        // Add the rule to the top of the rewrite list
        'top' );
}
```

Then **Save Changes** on you **Permalinks** settings page and then try again please. And let me know what happens.

Comment: unfortunately, doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Please try the updated code. @VishwasNavadaK

Comment: Tried adding the code and saving the permalinks. No change in permalink structure yet.